# Understanding the intuition behind the direct proof of the closed form expression for the sum S of the first n positive integers.

Tags: summation, proof-explanation

I understand the proof by induction, however I would like to understand the intuition behind why when doing the direct proof we simply layout the the sum forwards and backwards and add the two as such:

$$S= 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (n-1) + n $$
$$S = n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + 2 + 1$$
$$2S = (n + 1) + (n + 1) + (n + 1) + ... + (n + 1) + (n + 1) = n(n+1)$$ (then just divide by 2)

How do we figure out that doing such procedure will give us the appropriate formula? What's the general essence of such reasoning that can help us to reason other proofs of different nature?

Comment: When you ask, "How do we figure out that doing such procedure will give us the appropriate formula?", it seems like you are not really understanding the three lines of the proof. Which aspect is puzzling you?

Comment: "How do we figure out that doing such procedure will give us the appropriate formula?" -- I'm not really sure how to answer this beyond saying "a pattern emerges and visibly works." I feel one could draw comparisons to (versions of) the story of Gauss being punished in school by adding up the first $100$ positive integers, and solving it almost instantly by noticing a very similar pattern. Just now one would take it to an arbitrary number of integers.

Comment: "How do we figure out that doing such procedure will give us the appropriate formula?"I think two things are needed: 1) you must be gifted with a talent for mathematics. 2) you must "seek" for such patterns and think about them lots of times.

Comment: The idea used does *not* work for summing the first $N$ squares, cubes, and so on. Try it! Maybe this proof is not as versatile as you thought.